# Read a zip entry and save it in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, zip

Ack.  I am trying to open a specific entry in a zip file archive and store the contents in a string, instead of saving it to a file.  I cannot use disk space for this per the client.

Here's what I have:

```
  string scontents = "";
  byte[] abbuffer = null;
  MemoryStream oms = new MemoryStream();
  try
  {
    //get the file contents
    ozipentry.Open().CopyTo(oms);
    int length = (int)oms.Length;  // get file length
    abbuffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
    int icount;                            // actual number of bytes read
    int isum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

    // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
    while ((icount = oms.Read(abbuffer, isum, length - isum)) > 0)
    {
      isum += icount;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
    }
    scontents = BytesToString(abbuffer); <----abbuffer is filled with Ascii 0
  }
  finally
  {
    oms.Close();
  }
```

The variable abbuffer is supposed to hold that contents of the stream, but all it holds is a bunch of ascii zeros, which I guess means it didn't read (or copy) the stream!  But I do not get any error messages or anything.  Can someone tell me how to get this working?

I've looked everywhere on stack and on the web, and no where does anyone answer this question specifically for ASP.NET 4.5 ZipArchive library.  I cannot use any other library, so if you offer an answer in that, while it would be educational, won't help me at all in this instance.  Thanks so much for any help!

One more thing.  'ozipentry' is of type ZipArchiveEntry and is an element in a ZipArchive Entries array. (ie ozipentry = oziparchive.Entries[i])

Oops.  One more thing!  The function 'BytesToString' is not included, because it is irrelevant.  Before the function is called, the abbuffer array is already filled with 0's

Comment: I do not understand the point of copying the entry stream to a MemoryStream, but if you must do that, then set the `Memorystream.Position` property to 0 before trying to read from it. Why not just create a `StreamReader` based on the entry stream and use that to get the desired string?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that too.  Didn't see your comment until I posted an answer...what I did is, I think, what you were basically saying.  Someone at the client site told me to use memorystream, and like an idiot, I said, 'yup'!  Instead of thinking, um, why?

Answer (score 5):

Ok. Sorry for being so dense.  I realized I was overthinking this.  I changed to function to do this:

```
    osr = new StreamReader(ozipentry.Open(), Encoding.Default);
    scontents = osr.ReadToEnd();
```

And it worked fine!  Didn't even have to worry about Encoding...